# Getting the JSON string from a Twitter search result into Java to be parsed

Tags: java, json, parsing, twitter

I am trying to get the JSON data from a Twitter search request such as this [link text](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@noradio&rpp=1) into my Java program so that I can parse it using Gson. How would I get the data from that URL into Java? Would I use an http request or something else? I've seen JSONRequest.get, but I can't see where that's coming from at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) if you want to do it with plain java.

I'd recommend using the [apache commons http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/index.html) if possible

Answer (score 0):

Most JSON parsers accept input streams, some even just URL; so either pass URL, or create input stream from one. If Gson does not allow that, maybe ask on user list what's the proper way. And maybe there is either a simple way, or support can be added.

And like PF already mentioned, it's just a regular HTTP connection that you need, nothing JSON specific is needed (except maybe for specifying content type you except, using general content-type specification method(s)).